# OGR error creating feature -N: sqlite3_step() failed: UNIQUE constraint failed: layer.rowid (n)

Tags: pyqgis, spatialite, sqlite

Im in QGIS writing a plugin to syncronize 2 spatialite databases. I perfom a test to delete a feature in database A, then I click my syncronizer. And then I get this error in the message pane, not any errors in the python log. My script to update features uses

```
max_id = max([f.id() for f in active_layer.getFeatures()])
active_layer_set = set([f[idstr] for f in active_layer.getFeatures()])

# Iterate through features in the second layer
for feature in second_layer.getFeatures():
  # Check if the feature's special ID is not in the active layer
  if feature[idstr] not in active_layer_set:
    max_id +=1
    feature.setId(max_id)
    # Add the feature to the active layer
    active_layer.addFeatures([feature])
```

I think its a bug that the error is not trown back to python.